# iOS 9 UISearchBar hides cursor on second use

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I am using a UISearchController and associated UISearchBar in a table view controller.  The search bar is added to the navigation bar.  Here is what happens.

1. Enter view.  Search bar shows in nav bar.
2. Touch search bar, cursor appears and I can enter text.  (Note that I have set the tintColor to make the cursor a shade of orange.  This works fine.
3. After entering some search text, touch search button in keyboard.  Keyboard hides, cursor goes away, search happens and results are populated.
4. Touch search bar again.  Keyboard comes up and I can enter new text but the cursor no longer shows in the search bar.

I have tried a ton of different fixes including re-setting the tint color in various delegate functions, forcing the controller active, calling becomeFirstResponder (even though the keyboard is up).  Nothing has worked.

Note that the cursor does re-appear if I "deep" press the search bar (which also selects the text currently in the bar) on an iPhone 6S Plus.

Any suggestions appreciated.